# UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge not appearing in iphone 4

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I tried to create an activity indicator using the following code

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(160, 160.0,40.0,40.0);
progressIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]autorelease];
[progressIndicator startAnimating];
progressIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
progressIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
[progressIndicator sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:progressIndicator];
```

This code is working correctly in all devices except iphone 4(ie. indicator not showing in iphone 4). For that reason, i was forced to change the UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge to UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray so that activity indicator is shown in all devices. Can anyone explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi
i have the same problem as yours
however, actually the indicator is shown.
It may seem to be a hardware problem.
I guess that the retina display can not display the white display properly with white background.
because when the indicator was displayed on the black background, i could check that it worked.
I hope it may help you

Comment: u r rt... when i tried with the black background.. it really worked fine in iphone 4 also... tanks..

Comment: This answer isn't correct--it is not a hardware problem.  @JSW's answer below is correct.  They changed the graphic asset in ios v4.0 so that it doesn't have a drop-shadow and doesn't show up on a white background.

Answer (score 4):

The large white indicator has no drop shadow on ios 4 like it does on ios 3. I'm not sure why apple removed the shadow, but the indicator is there. You just can't see it on a white background anymore. Use the grey one, or put a background behind it.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket against this a week after iOS 4 came out and have yet to receive even an acknowledgment of the issue.  It works in iOS < 4, broken in iOS >= 4.  Doubt it'll be fixed any time soon.

Comment: @xydev - Of course, sorry it wasn't more helpful.  No idea how this one got through Apple's QA.